# 3rd Party Password Autofill Extension

Tags: ios, autofill

How does apple make sure that hackers can't push fake apps with fake domains to work with iOS password autofill feature?

For example, if a hacker creates an app with its domain as linkedin.com, the user could be using the Password Autofill feature and fake app will pass linkedin.com as service identifier to Autofill extension.

I found some documentation around how associated domains work for universal link to make sure that authenticity of service identifier or domain is ensured.

Here is the link to tha documentaion I read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains

Also if password autofill uses the same mechanism as universal link and with associated domains in an app allowing mutiple domains. which domain would autofill extension pick up, when we try to use autofill extention with a native app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a two-way link between the app and the web site.

The app lists its associated domains in the `info.plist` file.
The web site at the associated domain provides the bundle IDs its supported apps in `apple-app-site-association` file.

In order for password autofill to work, both parts of the link need to be in place.

Looking at the example you proposed for linkedin.com.

- The attacker can publish an app that lists `linkedin.com` as an associated domain.
- The app has a bundle id, say, `com.badapple.trickyapp`
- This bundle id won't be listed in the linkedin.com `apple-app-site-association` file, because the attacker doesn't have the ability to change that file; It is controlled by linked in.
- Because there is no match, autofill won't be automatically triggered.

How about the other way?

- The linkedin.com `apple-app-site-association` will contain the bundle id for their app, say, `com.linkedin.app`.
- The attacker can't publish an app with that bundle id, because there is already an app on the store with that id (The LinkedIn official app), so they have to use a different bundle id.
- Also, the bundle ID needs to include the team identifier, so only apps from the LinkedIn *team* can possibly match
- This is back to the first case; no autofill

Essentially you need control of both the app and the website content for autofill to be triggered.

If there are multiple domains listed in an app, and the relevant site associations are in place, then iOS will offer multiple password choices on the quick type bar.  If there are more matches in the Keychain (or whatever password provider the user is using) then they can use the "passwords..." button to see all matches in a table view and choose the relevant account details.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot Paul for the detailed explanation.

Comment: One more question 
My app which has 3 associated domains 
eg: 
applinks: test.domain1.com, applinks: test.domain2.com, applinks: test.domain3.com. But my password autofill app is only getting 1 service Identifier and that too serviceIdentifier.identifier as only "domain3.com". While I'm expecting all the 3.

This is the call I'm referring too : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/ascredentialproviderviewcontroller/2968231-preparecredentiallistforservicei?language=objc